# Who are these "barbarian invaders from outside the galaxy"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

For some time I have been wondering about the following cryptic reference which appeared in the [Revenge of the Sith cross section book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_Incredible_Cross-Sections) concerning the "Venator" proto-star destroyers:

> These ships will see service for decades to come, as the Republic is transformed into the Empire. The Imperial Starfleet will justify its existence in unending war against separatist holdouts, dissident rebels **and even, it is rumored, deterring barbarian invaders from outside the galaxy**.

Here is the text as it appears in the book:

[image]

So here is my question: Who are these mysterious "barbarian invaders"? Is there something in the vast Star Wars universe to which this is probably referring, or is it an invention of the author?

I have tagged this question with "star wars legends" since the book was first published in 2005 and should probably be considered in that context.

Comment: [Yuuzhan-Vong](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong)?

Comment: Seems like a likely candidate... is this all it could be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only invaders from *outside* the galaxy I know of are [Yuuzhan-Vong](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong) (their page lists two other species from another galaxy, but those don't match the "barbaric" part of the description).

The author likely calls them barbarians because their religion, to which they adhered zealously, banned all technology. Everything used by Yuuzhan-Vong was organic in some way, even the generation ships they used to reach the galaxy far far away.

Their invasion was rather violent - same Wikia claims there were hundreds of trillions of causalities.

After the events of Episode VI, the New Republic was established (in Legends). I think it's only logical for them to use whatever remained after the Empire, including their ships.

I believe there was also a (Legends) theory that everything Palpatine did - getting rid of the Jedi, establishing the Empire - he did in order to protect the galaxy from Yuuzhan-Vong, whom he could sense were coming. It makes sense, really, because the Republic's military wasn't in the best shape, and Jedi were useless against them anyway because Force abilities had no effect on the invaders

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know. It surprises me that out of countless star wars books/etc there is nothing else from outside the galaxy.

Comment: Distances between galaxies exceed those within a galaxy by a factor of ten or more (depending where the galaxy is relative to clusters or voids).  With the sheer size of a galaxy, it's probably pretty rare for anyone/anything to travel between them.